# Invalid UIAccessibilitys 'tablist' error after installing react-native-vector-icons and running pod update on ios

Tags: ios, react-native, debugging, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I tried to install react-native-vector-icons and ran pod update and got the following error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcVr0.jpg
now this pops up but I can build and run the app just fine.
is this ok? and how can I fix this ?

**after this started happening I unlinked react-native-vector-icons and uninstalled it**
but for some reason I still get this error, now I tried debugging it and it seems to have some thing to do with "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs" package.

my package.json:

```
},
  "dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.1.1",
    "@viro-community/react-viro": "^2.20.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.65.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.11.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "fsevents": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.15.3",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing the same issue. And I resolved it.
Go to node_modules -> @react-navigation -> bottom-tabs.

Find all `accessibilityRole` (in file BottomTabBar and BottomTabItem -> it is located at `bottom-tabs/lib/commonjs/views` and `bottom-tabs/lib/module/views` and `bottom-tabs/src/views`) and change it to `none`.

I changed `accessibilityRole="tablist"` to `accessibilityRole="none"`
And change `accessibilityRole: Platform.select({ ios: 'button', default: 'tab' })` to `accessibilityRole: Platform.select({ ios: 'button', default: 'none' })`

This issue will be resolved. But when you install new package, you must do it again :))

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea what is the cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a problem with the built-in react-navigation tabs, but the issue went away when I created a [custom tab bar](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#tabbar).